# Javascript Object - Get Contents

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a javascript object which is basically an associative array from php.

The value of this object is :

```
{0Asvp4GYKiXtdFo2TzE1YURRYy1lSGUxSTF3aUNXd0E":"18\/11\/2013",
"0AuH2Ky77gNtudGt3WUJpRWZTV0FRTnl5UnpBcHFYZlE":"13\/11\/2013"}
```

I believe this is JSON Format, and I am wanting to grab only the first String, not the date. and put them both into an array. How is this possible?

Comment: Is this exactly how it's output? This is malformed if so... There should be another `"` before the first key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var object=/* json object from php */
var keys=[];

for(var key in object)
    keys.push(key);
```

This loops through each key on `object` and pushes it into an `keys` array.

Comment: Perfect, I never thought of this method. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers (Firefox 4+, Chrome 5+, Internet Explorer 9+, Opera 12+, Safari 5+) have [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var obj = {"0Asvp4GYKiXtdFo2TzE1YURRYy1lSGUxSTF3aUNXd0E":"18\/11\/2013", "0AuH2Ky77gNtudGt3WUJpRWZTV0FRTnl5UnpBcHFYZlE":"13\/11\/2013"}

console.log(Object.keys(obj)) // [ '0Asvp4GYKiXtdFo2TzE1YURRYy1lSGUxSTF3aUNXd0E','0AuH2Ky77gNtudGt3WUJpRWZTV0FRTnl5UnpBcHFYZlE' ]
```